# Horizontal and Vertical ViewPager together

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a list of items (custom objects). This is the main list.
Each of the item in the list has another list of data (URLS). This is the sublist.

I want to show the data from main-list implemented as a `vertical viewpager`. So, flipping in vertical direction changes the items from the main list. And for the data in each item in the main-list should have the sublist implemented as a `horizontal viewpager`. So, if the fling is in the horizontal direction it shows me the items in the sublist corresponding to the item in the main list.

Also, vertical fling to any item in the sublist should be able to take to the next item of the mainlist.

Essentially, I am looking at implementing both direction view-pagers. Implementing view-pager in one direction seems to be pretty straight forward. i.e. `FragmentActivity` hosting a `Fragment` and a adapter class implementing a `FragmentPagerAdapter`. But, how should I go about implementing the above functionality?

I tried playing around with some third-party libraries including `DirectionalViewPager` (it's deprecated though). I am planning to use `GestureListeners` and animations together to build this effect.

Any pointers on what could be the best way to approach this problem would be very helpful.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you got a solution? I also looking for same implementation. If you got solution can you share it with me?

Answer (score 3):

I built a solution combining a **horizontal viewpager** (the parent) with **vertical viewpagers** (each child) on a single view called **DoubleViewPager**. I overrode the following methods on vertical viewpager:

- `public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)`
- `public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)`

When the user triggers those events on each child, they pass it to the parent. Then, if the event is vertical, the child processes it, otherwise, if the event is horizontal, the parent processes it.

Take a look to my [DoubleViewPager](https://github.com/juliome10/DoubleViewPager) library, where I implemented this strategy.